# 2d array with several variables in R

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, frequency

I am having problems building a 2D array out of several different variables. The two dimensions are supposed to make up the columns and rows of the matrix. In total I have a df with 19 different dummy variables [0,1]. I want 11 of these variables to make up one dimension, i.e. 11 different kinds of majors you can study at university, and I want the 8 other variables to make up the second dimension, i.e. 8 different German universities. Hence, I will end up with two different dimensions (majors and universities) which both comprise several different types (majors: law, psychology, political science etc.; German universities: Humboldt, TU Munich, Heidelberg).

So my questions are:

1. How can I construct this 2d array matrix in R?
2. Which command do I need to use in order to put specific variables into one dimension (columns) and other variables into the second dimension (rows)?
3. How can I then measure the frequency (sums of 1) of each cell (frequency table)?

[I want to do something like this but with the sum of 1s in each cell and the rows should be the different universities and the colums the different majors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAeM6.gif)

```
     A = matrix(
   + c("psychology", "law", "political science", "Humboldt", "Heidelberg", etc.) # the 19 different variables 
   +   nrow=8,              # number of rows 
   +   ncol=11,              # number of columns 
   +   byrow = TRUE)        # fill matrix by rows 

   A                      # print the matrix 
                   [psychology] [law] [political science] [history] [etc.] 
     [Humbooldt]       890       1041         563            441     ...
     [Heidelberg]      121        517         470            231     ... 
     [other univ]      ...        ...         ...            ...     ...
```

I am quite new to R and also new to this forum so I am unsure whether the way I am asking this question is completely correct. Sincere apologies if not, I will try my best next time! I have been looking through similar posts on stackoverflow but so far I couldn't find a suited answer for my problem.

[this is how my df looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEcsQ.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post sample input and expected output, as is the question is not clear.

Comment: Just did. Hopefully this will help!

Comment: @Lualo, how does your initial dataframe look? Can you provide the output of either head(df) function or str(df) function of your dataframe? It will be easier to understand how you arrive at your output "cell values" (890,121, etc...) in your output.

Comment: I just edited my post with the information you requested. All the variables are dummy variables so the cell values are just the sum of all the "1 (yes)" answers of the variables (the quantity). Thanks very much for your help!